# Implementing forward-backward algorithm: confusion around presence of start and stop states in transition matrix

Tags: hidden-markov-model, forward-backward

I'm attempting to implement the forward-backward algorithm. I have my observations and I am attempting to estimate $A$ and $B$. Looking at the algorithm, one thing I'm having trouble figuring out, is whether there are rows for the non-emitting start ($S_0$) and end states ($S_F$) in $A$ and $B$. For example, assuming there are two emitting states $\{S_1, S_2\}$ and two observations $\{O_1, O_2\}$, should we have $A^{2 \times 2}$ and $B^{2 \times 2}$ or $A^{4 \times 4}$ and $B^{4 \times 2}$?

I'm confused because we use $a_{0j}$ and $a_{Fj}$ in the algorithm. But that would mean that we should have rows for these states in $A$ and $B$. This giving me weird results when training because I end up getting non-zero values for $a_{00}$, $a_{0F}$, $a_{F0}$, and $a_{FF}$, when these should be zero.